# Mockito Nullable ArgumentCaptor Value

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Is it possible to have a nullable ArgumentCaptor?

I'm trying to use the below method

```
    public Win getWin() {
        ArgumentCaptor<Win> winCaptor = ArgumentCaptor
                .forClass(Win.class);
        Mockito.verify(producer, Mockito.atMostOnce()).accept(winCaptor.capture());
        return winCaptor.getValue();
    }
```

this works fine when `producer.accept(win)` is called but I'd like it to return null if it's not. Is this possible?

I'm currently getting this error

```
No argument value was captured!
You might have forgotten to use argument.capture() in verify()...
...or you used capture() in stubbing but stubbed method was not called.
Be aware that it is recommended to use capture() only with verify()
```

Comment: I think for the `null` case, it's be cleaner to `verify(mock).method(null)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `winCaptor.getAllValues()` method. It will not throw an exception if the `accept()` method was not called. Instead, it will return an empty list.